# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm really bad at handling promises, and am trying to figure out why I'm getting this error. Here's what I'm doing:

```
testFunction(user_email, email_html).then(() => {
    //Some stuff
}).catch((error) => {
    //Some other stuff
})

function testFunction(user_email, email_html) {
    if (user_email) {
        sendEmail({ recipient: user_email, subject: "Some words", body: email_html, html: true })
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

sendEmail is a Firebase cloud function.

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    let is_html = data.html
    console.log("sendEmail is_html is ", is_html)
    let msg = {}
    if (!is_html) {
        msg = {
            to: data.recipient,
            from: 'contact@mydomain.com',
            subject: data.subject,
            text: data.body
        }
    } else {
        msg = {
            to: data.recipient,
            from: 'contact@mydomain.com',
            subject: data.subject,
            html: data.body
        }
    }
    console.log("sendEmail complete")
    return sgMail.send(msg)
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: testFunction is returning either undefined or true, but never a promise. Why would you expect that you can call .then on it? I'm only guessing here, but maybe you wanted to mark testFunction async (so it always returns a promise) and then also _return_ the result of the sendEmail call (or await it) so that you can wait for it...?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by using async in front of the client-side function declaration rather than the Firebase function itself, and await in front of the call to the Firebase function.

Answer (score -1):

If the test function is executed successfully it returns a value which is placed in the () inside then else it returns an error and goes to catch.
So if you wantd to print the result of the test function you would write:

```
testFunction(user_email, email_html).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

But you need the res property ti act on it else if you dont care about the result as long as the excecution was successful you would write:

```
testFunction(user_email, email_html).then().catch((error) => {
    //Some other stuff
})
```

or if that doesn't work try skiping the then completly and write:

```
testFunction(user_email, email_html).catch((error) => {
    //Some other stuff
})
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said, but I can't read "res" because the error happens as soon as the code reaches ".then"

So it never reaches that log statement showing the output. Is there anything else I can try?

In my actual code I'm chaining 5 promises, so the last suggestion wouldn't work for me.

Comment: I edited the code within testFunction to return sendEmail.....then((res) => {...

res returned an object that said status code 202, which looking up means "the request has been accepted for processing but the processing has not been completed; in fact, processing may not have started yet."

And my cloud function doesn't return an error. Is this a syntax problem or what else can I try?

Comment: Perhaps you could try to define your cloud function as async but I can't come up with anything else: 
```exports.sendEmail = async ...(...)=?{...}```

Comment: I tried putting async in front of (data and await in front of sgMail.send(msg) but that didn't make a difference. Thank you for trying to help though.